# How to create download link in ADF?

Tags: java, download, oracle-adf

I am using `jdev 11.1.1.5.0.`. In my use case, I want to create a download link. When the user clicks on the link, the file should get downloded automatically (like download servlet).

The code is as follows:

```
HttpServletResponse response= (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();                                                         response.setContentType("text/plain");                                                          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+part.getFileName());     response.setContentType("text/plain");                                                  response.setHeader("ContentDisposition","attachment;filename="+part.getFileName());        InputStreaminput=part.getInputStream();                                                     int read=0;        
  byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];                                                    OutputStream os =response.getOutputStream();    


while((read=input.read(bytes))!=-1)
{os.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
os.flush();                                                   
os.close();
```

But it is not working. My requirement is that want to create dynamic link (URL) and when the user clicks on link, the file is downloaded. Is there any other way to do this?   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [commandLink](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_commandLink.html)  and provide [File Download Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/apirefs.1112/e17491/tagdoc/af_fileDownloadActionListener.html) to that and code to that listener

```
    <af:commandButton text="Say Hello">
      <af:fileDownloadActionListener filename="hello_txt"
                                contentType="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
                                method="#{bean.sayHello}"/>
    </af:commandButton>


public void sayHello(FacesContext context, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
  OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
  w.write("Hi there!");
  // The stream is automatically closed, but since we wrapped it,
  // we'd better flush our writer
  w.flush();
}
```

Comment: hi , actually i have create command Button programatically and alose tried following code

Comment: RichCommandImageLink bt=new RichCommandImageLink();
bt.setText("mybt "+part.getFileName());                                      
MethodExpression returnMethodExpression=fileDownladActionListenerMethodExpression("#{pageFlowScope.jagranmailclient.downloadAttachment}");
FileDownloadActionListener fileDownLoadListener = new FileDownloadActionListener();
 fileDownLoadListener.setMethod(returnMethodExpression);
 fileDownLoadListener.setContentType("plain/text");
 fileDownLoadListener.setFilename(fileName);
testbt.addActionListener(fileDownLoadListener);